Gitlab CI/CD with docker:stable as base image, install JDK but /bin/sh: eval: line 155: java: not found upon java --version
I would like to invoke the java command as part of a Gitlab pipeline.
The pipeline looks like:
build:
  image: docker:stable
  stage: build
  script:
    - wget https://download.oracle.com/graalvm/23/latest/graalvm-jdk-23_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
    - tar -xvf graalvm-jdk-23_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
    - mv graalvm-jdk-23.0.1+11.1 /opt/
    - JAVA_HOME='/opt/graalvm-jdk-23.0.1+11.1'
    - PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
    - echo $PATH
    - export PATH
    - java --version
# // later here will download maven, compile a graalvm native image, and docker push it
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
    DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
    DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "$DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR/client"
  services:
    - docker:dind


However, when trying to execute the java command, I am getting: /bin/sh: eval: line 155: java: not found
I tried moving the folder, chmod 777, providing relative, absolute path, but always getting /bin/sh: eval: line 155: java: not found.
I was expecting this step, the invocation of java --version to succeed.
How to invoke java command properly?

Did you try to use a java image instead of docker ? You can use the docker image in another job to push the image after the build.

This is a good idea @fmdaboville ! In my example, there is nothing after java, but actually,  I would need to download maven, and many other utilities. This is why I would prefer to use a simple docker:stable as base, so that I can download each and every (18 of them) manually

But I think it will be easier for you if you split in several job and use the correct image for each of them, and pass artifacts with keywords "needs". There are some images with several tools, for example, maven image also have java.

I would suggest to use graalvm image directly instead of slim docker image
graalvm and sdkman
In download page there are container options already, you can see both images with maven work below
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
  DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "$DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR/client"

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build

build-with-native-image:
  stage: build
  image: container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/native-image:23
  script:
    - microdnf install unzip zip findutils
    - java --version
    - native-image --version
    - curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
    - source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
    - sdk install maven
    - mvn package

# Job using the JDK container
build-with-jdk:
  stage: build
  image: container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/jdk:23
  script:
    - microdnf install unzip zip findutils
    - java --version
    - curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
    - source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
    - sdk install maven
    - mvn test

Running example here
docker image
The problem in the yml is using docker:stable which is stripped from everything, even glibc does not exist in the container, So below you can see debian based docker image and do the firther steps with scripts
build:
  image: debian:bullseye-slim
  stage: build
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget tar
    - wget https://download.oracle.com/graalvm/23/latest/graalvm-jdk-23_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
    - tar -xvf graalvm-jdk-23_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
    - mv graalvm-jdk-23.0.1+11.1 /opt/
    - JAVA_HOME=/opt/graalvm-jdk-23.0.1+11.1
    - export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
    - /opt/graalvm-jdk-23.0.1+11.1/bin/java --version
    - java --version
# // later here will download maven, compile a graalvm native image, and docker push it
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
    DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
    DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "$DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR/client"
  services:
    - docker:dind

Working example here

This is indeed correct. I am going to follow this sample. Thank you @ozkanpakdil. Upvote  accepted
